# Can you nest System.Data.Entity.Include more than 2 levels?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to use Entity Framework's `Include` method more than 2 levels down and it doesn't seem to be working. Is it possible to do something like the following:

```
db
  .Table1
  .Include(t1 => t1.Table2)
  .Include(t1 => t1.Table2.Select(t2 => t2.Table3))
```

I have tried doing this and it doesn't work, so I have had to make 2 queries instead, which I wish to avoid.

Comment: Your code should work. What is the error message?

Comment: No error message, it just doesn't do the join and return the `t2 => t2.Tables` property

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.Table1
  .Include("Table2")
  .Include("Table2.Table3"));
```

or simply

```
db.Table1
  .Include("Table2.Table3"));
```